# Dependency injection and Model entities - the right way ?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

My symfony2 application has the following structure:

There is a service `data_provider`, which gets data from various external sources and represents it as entity objects.

Some objects has relations. Currently I am loading relations in controller or helper-services if needed.

It is not very convenient, sometimes I want to get relations from my entity ojbect. To do this I need access to `data_provider` service.

I want to implement something like doctrine lazy-loading, what is the right way of doing this ?

Some obvious solutions - to inject `data_provider` in every entity instacne, or to some static property, or to make some static methods in service, or to use evenet dispatcher, but I don't think it is the right way

Comment: Doctrine 2 has an ObjectManagerInterface which has access to your entity meta data and is basically responsible for things like lazy loading.  The standard Doctrine EntityManager implements this interface to do all of it's magic.  I suppose that you might be able to adjust your data_provider to implement this interface as well which in turn would give you access a great deal of the Doctrine functionality.  Never tried it myself so I can't offer any help on how to do this.  But if it is a big project then it might be worth digging into the guts of Doctrine.

Comment: Thank you for directions to search. :)

https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/PersistentObject.php

The interface is called `ObjectManagerAwareInterface`.
It seems that instance of ObjectManager is set in private static property of base object class during the initialization of ObjectManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some research of ObjectManagerInterface as Cerad suggested, and found this peace of code: https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/PersistentObject.php

PersistentObject implements ObjectManagerAware interface, it has private static property where ObjectManager is stored.

So I ended with this:

```
class DataProvider
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        ...
        AbstractEntity::setDataProvider($this);
    }
}

abstract class AbstractEntity
{
    private static $dataProvider;
    public static function setDataProvider() {...};
    protected static function getDataProvider() {...};
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The main purpose of services in Symfony (and not only) is exactly this one - to deliver distinguished functionalitys **globally** over your project.

In this regard, a single service, in your case - dataProvider, should always deliver a single entity. If you have to deal with multiple entities returned from one data source, wrap the data source deliverer into a service itself, and then define one service per each entity with the deliverer injected into it.

Then you can inject the respective entity services into your controllers.

Comment: My dataProvider service returns a factory, which creates some objects. Think about doctrine service, it works the same way. `data_provider` delivers instance of DataProvider, which make some externals request, gets some data like json object or json array of objects and wraps it in php classes.
Some objects fetched from externals sources have relations. I want to lazy load this related objects.

Comment: So, as I said - you can inject your `data_provider` service into as much services, as different data types you have. Then use those services into the controllers.

Comment: What relation exactly would you need from your `data_provider` into a controller? As you describe it, `data_provider` is just a factory, and as such, in must have only opaque relations.

Comment: Example:

I make request to `data_provider` to get list of cars. It returns 1000 Car class objects. 

Car has some special offers which can be retrived from `data_provider`.

I want to get special offers only for car #399, not for all cars. And i want to get it from Car#399 object

Comment: I would do that in 2 ways, depending on the situation:
1. If the data deliverer for the "all cars" and "specific car info" is one and the same - keep everything into `data_provider` and implement those into 2 separate methods.
2. If the data deliverers are different, split both into 2 different services.

Then, again, inject whatever needed into the controllers.

Comment: I think you didnt understand the original question due to my inaccuracy. `data_provider` - is an abstraction, actually there are many layers like different adapters, cache, output formatters, etc. Question is not about how to get data, and not about how inject service into controller.